# update table without using update statement

Tags: sql

can anyone tell that how to update some records of a table without using update statement. it is possible using select statement.

Comment: No it is not possible with a SELECT statement. This sounds to me like someone does not have UPDATE privileges, but still wants to UPDATE. IF that's the case I would address the privileges issue.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can ***update*** the table without ***update*** statement.

Comment: Often database permissions are given for select OR update OR delete because each has a very specific effect on the tables. It's highly unlikely any database will allow a SELECT statement to make an underlying change UNLESS there is a trigger or stored procedure underneath that has been set up by the system administrator to have a secondary effect.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with a select statement.

You can delete a row and insert the same row + your changes which is in many ways like an update, but will cause lots of trouble with foreign keys.

Oh, and your DBA might kill you.

Comment: What a strange answer, how do you delete and insert with a select?

Comment: I haven't said that it is a select!? My first sentence negates the statement in the second sentence of the OP. My second sentence answers the question in the first sentence of the OP

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
REPLACE INTO tablename(primary key, ...{rest of the columns in the table}) 
VALUES(the same primary key, new values );
```

This will delete the previous row and insert a new row with the same primary key and updated column values. Not so much worthwhile, but maybe there is some other way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what tools you are using and what you actually want to achieve.

- There are libraries which allow you to update data you got from a select statement. (eg. ORM's like NHibernate, I think ADO.NET also). These libraries are writing the update statements for you
- You can use functions or triggers which change data when you just perform a select statement. In these functions or trigger, you still have an update statement.
- For security reasons, you have to make sure that nobody injects an update statement into your select statement. So it is not just save to only perform a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

> how to update some records of a table
>   without using update statement.

Use a [`MERGE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29) statement.

> it is possible using select statement.

Logically, an update is a delete and an insert:  `INSERT INTO..SELECT` to a staging table, modifying the data as appropriate, then `DELETE` then `INSERT INTO..SELECT` from staging table.

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance you were asking how this happened when a module ran a select statement it created, then you need to read up on SQL injection. You cannot do an update without an update statment of some kind (includiing not only update but doing delete and then insert or useiing merge) and the user must have update permission on a table, but you can add an update to a select statement that is dymanically created if you haven't correctly parametized it to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

We can update a table without using update keyword and with just 'insert' or 'insert into select' keyword if the table has audit fields such as create date or eff date, delete date or ineff date etc.

If you have a requirement where you have only few fields to update then you may need to use temp table first to fetch and store the existing record and then you need to perform

```
INSERT INTO originaltablename
(
all fields to be inserted (must include all non nullable fields along with the fields to be updated)
)
SELECT 
tempfield1
tempfield2
@inputfield1
@inputfield2
tempfield3
FROM #temptable
--Uncomment below portion if any field is missing from input n temptable too or need to fetch from some other original table 
/*INNER JOIN originaltablename
WHERE 
originaltablefield = @someinputfieldconditional
AND create_datetime is not null
AND delete_datetime is null */
```