# How to update table without using update keyword

Tags: sql

I have table a ,table b with same columns .I want to replace the value in table b with table a value without using update keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Comment: This is either homework or a misguided question, but in any case I think your only option would be to delete those records from the target table and then do an insert; but you would never do this in practice because of data consistency issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646327/update-table-without-using-update-statement

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? In SQL Server you might use [MERGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update table without using update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646327/update-table-without-using-update-statement)

Comment: delete then insert

Comment: @ocasoprotal but, technically, merge statement uses update keyword.. :)

Comment: DROP TABLEB; 
    RENAME TABLEA TABLEB

Comment: @CaiusJard D'oh you are correct. Too early in the morning and no coffee yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

The question could use a bit more detail on the table structure, what exactly you're trying to accomplish, and what precludes you from using UPDATE, but here goes:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable (col1, col2, col3, ...)

INSERT INTO #tempTable
SELECT 
 b.col1
 , b.col2
 , a.col3
 , ...
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.col1 = b.col1

DELETE FROM b
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM a)

INSERT INTO b
SELECT
 col1
 , col2
 , col3
 , ...
FROM #TempTable
```

Which of course makes the bold assumption that Table a and b share a primary key,  and that Table b doesn't have any constraint that would prevent deletion of matched rows. Please, provide some more detail and I'll update my answer accordingly.